# can azure devop boards order PBI base on priority?

Tags: azure-devops

We use azure devop board to manage our work. In the board we have new, approved, in progress etc to indicate the status of individual PBIs.

What we found is that when I create a new PBI, azure board will put it at the top of new issues column, even if I give it a very long priority (seems it is ordered by creation date).

Is there a way to order the columns base on Priority or some other field by default?
[image]